# very bad disparity map using Stereo SGBM

Tags: opencv

I'm using Stereo SGBM of openCV to generate disparity map from a couple of images satellite,
the result is very bad even when I change the parameters. what should I do ?

Answer (score 6):

I developped a tool similar to the one given in Robst's answer, but a little more convenient, and cross-platform. You can find it [here](https://github.com/vmarquet/opencv-disparity-map-tuner).

[image: example screenshot]

Comment: your link leads to the project posted as previous answer

Answer (score 0):

SGBM parameter tuner based on vmarquet's great QT GUI for BM:

https://github.com/hitimo/opencv-disparity-map-tuner

Might be helpful to find the correct parameter set.

Answer (score -2):

You could try StereoBM to see if you can get better results. You could use the tool developed by Martin Peris found [here](http://blog.martinperis.com/2011/08/opencv-stereo-matching.html) to modify the parameters. It will be much easier with the GUI provided. You could do something similar for StereoSGBM. Make sure your images are properly rectified.

Regards

Comment: can you tell me please what the parameter numberOfDisparities refers to? because I think that it is the one I should adjust

Comment: Hello, the parameter `ndisparities` quantifies the expected maximum disparity you can have. You can find a nice explanation of the parameter here: [link](http://www.pressingquestion.com/4747621/Black-Columns-In-The-Disparity-Map-When-Using-Stereobm)

Comment: The link is broken. Leads to some phishing site.